# create a table where the values corresponding to true in one column and false in other, group by of date

Tags: sql

***Changed the table name and values***

I am creating a new table from an existing table(t_gen_std), which has a column with true/false values. Few other columns include Cust_ID(unique), values(from 1-5), T_F_data(true/false), as_of_date. I want to create a table that outputs a table with ID, as_of_date, sum_of_trues for the corresponding date, sum_of_false for the corresponding date.

I have done this for the 'true' values
select sum(values) from t_gen_std where T_F_data = 'true' group by as_of_date, Cust_ID

and this for 'false' values
select sum(values) from t_gen_std where T_F_data = 'false' group by as_of_date, Cust_ID

but I am not sure how to put these two together and output into the same table. I am doing this Hue with impala engine.

Original table..

```
Cust_ID(string)  Values(string)      T_F_data(string)        as_of_date(time stamp)
   1                   5                 True                 05/15/2012
   2                   5                 True                 05/14/2012
   1                   2                 False                05/05/2013
   3                   4                 True                 05/15/2012
   2                   2                 False                05/14/2012
```

Expected table..

```
ID          date                   true_values             false_values
```

Comment: Try with `sum(case when T_F_data=true then 1 else 0 end)`

Comment: Thanks Jamie, this is an interesting approach, but what I am looking for is the sum of values in the true_values, false_values not no of repetitions. My bad, my question wasn't specific.

Comment: I got it, thanks Jamie

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach

```
SELECT 
    Cust_ID
    ,MAX(IIF(T_F_data = 'True',as_of_date,NULL)) AS true_date
    ,MAX(IIF(T_F_data = 'True',Values,NULL)) AS true_values

    ,MAX(IIF(T_F_data = 'False',as_of_date,NULL)) AS False_date
    ,MAX(IIF(T_F_data = 'False',Values,NULL)) AS false_values

FROM Some_TABLE 

GROUP BY 
    Cust_ID
```